# Samsung android 6.0 how to get dual sim call logs with sim slot id?

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, samsung-mobile, slot, dual-sim

Samsung(dual sim) before offical android 6.0(not cm) device, I could get call logs with sim slot id, but Samsung(dual sim) android 6.0+ device I get an issue:

```
String  slotId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID));

<i>slotId</i> = null; but in another device (Huawei mate 8) is work fine
```

Did samsung modify the com.android.providers.contacts and contacts2.db?

Can someone guide through the solution for this?

Comment: Hey man your answer was really helpful.. One problem though I am not able to register a content observer on this uri... any ideas?

Comment: In my app, just register a content observer  on Uri.parse(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);  this uri is base database table,uri = Uri.parse("content://logs/call"); is a view create from it,so just create one content observer  on Uri.parse(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);  is work fine, have fine and good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update news : I find one solution

```
  boolean s_bSamsung;
if (Build.VERSION_CODES.M <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT && s_bSamsung){
   uri = Uri.parse("content://logs/call");
}else {
  uri = Uri.parse(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);
}
```

use sim_id find sim slot

Comment: but i getting simid=4 for sim 1 and simid=1 sim 2.   what is that?? then how to solve this?.